# How to use Class object in Objective C code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have four screens that are exactly the same except they use four different classes. I thought I could reduce them to one by putting this property in my header:

```
@property Class *classType;
```

Then I could set the class and be done.

HOWEVER, when I try to use classType like the following:

```
NSArray *myArray = [classType allobjects];
```

I get the following: "Bad receiver type __unsafe_unretained Class *"

This really doesn't make much sense. The class method returns and NSArray. When I use the explicit class name there is no error and everything works fine.

I'm using xcode 4.5 with ARC.

Comment: Your should inherit base class or use protocol for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
@property Class classType;
```

Note the missing *. Class is like id, the pointer type is implied.

Comment: Okay, that fixed one side of it. Now when in my main class I have         controller.classType = MyOtherClass; it tosses me the error "Unexpected interface name MyOtherClass: expected expression". BTW thanks for the catch on the "*" totally overlooked that.

Comment: Perfect. I've been writing objc for almost 15 years and this is the first time I've really needed to do this. lol - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Quick search on Google, even better in the runtime's headers:

```
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
```

The `Class` type is a pointer itself - you don't need an extra `*` sign when declaring the property.